# Can't find my mistake (codewars, js, 8 kyu)

Tags: javascript

The task:

You received a whatsup message from an unknown number. Could it be from that girl/boy with a foreign accent you met yesterday evening?

Write a simple function to check if the string contains the word hallo in different languages.

These are the languages of the possible people you met the night before:

```
hello - english
ciao - italian
salut - french
hallo - german
hola - spanish
ahoj - czech republic
czesc - polish
```

Notes

you can assume the input is a string.

to keep this a beginner exercise you don't need to check if the greeting is a subset of word (Hallowen can pass the test)
function should be case insensitive to pass the tests

my solution:

```
function validateHello(greetings) {
  
  
    for ( let str in greetings){
     let res = str.toLowerCase();
      if (res == "hello") {
      return true;
    } else if (res == "ciao") {
      return true;
    } else if (res =="salut") {
      return trres
    } else if (res == "hallo") {
      return true;
    } else if (res == "hola") {
      return true;
    } else if (res == "ahoj") {
      return true;
    } else if (res == "czesc") {
      return true ;
```

Comment: *"Hallowen can pass the test"*: you didn't implement that.

Comment: add `console.log(str)` right after the `for` line and look what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your mistake:

```
else if (res =="salut") {
  return trres
```

Change `trres` to `true` to fix it.